# What is the difference between io.rest-assured vs jayway rest-assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

What is the difference between io.rest-assured vs jayway rest-assured? Which framework should i use for restfull webservice testing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

REST Assured has a new group id, io.rest-assured. Previously you depended on REST Assured like this (Maven):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
  <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

but now you do:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
  <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

From the documentation : https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/ReleaseNotes30#highlights

Answer (score 2):

Both io and jayway are maven dependencies. jayway is the older version(2.9.0) and io is the new version from (3.0.0). io.restassured is now updated to 3.1.0.

Refer link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured