# how to : intercept the request body from rest-assured

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I want intercept the request body and request headers before the reuqest sended from rest-assured(http://rest-assured.io/). But i'm not fund a method？ somebody help me ?

Comment: what code do you have so far?

Comment: yes , I have modified the rest-assured source code. but i want use the rest-assured API

Comment: could you please describe your initial task? Some examples, of desired request/response entities? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: io restassured is has new group idcompared to Jayway restassured.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016076/what-is-the-difference-between-io-rest-assured-vs-jayway-rest-assured For interceptor check whether this helps
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/usage#interceptors